# How to use xargs rm command to exclude directory

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have to write a shell script so that it should remove all the files except test.txt
When I run the script, it says Removal of Source file failed because dev_data is a directory.

```
ls | grep -v 'test.txt' | xargs rm
```

I want to write a shell script so that if there is a directory in the below path, it should skip the directory. The script should remove only the files inside the directory - dev_data

Error Log is given below:

```
ig_dir.sh process starts at: 
Wed Nov 2 08:08:09 IST 2022
```

---

```
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/alb/albt_shard/alb1/path1/path2/alb1/sub/alby/
/alb/albt_shard/alb1/path1/path2/alb1/sub/alby/dev_data/
/alb/albt_shard/alb1/path1/path2/alb1/sub/alby/dev_data/list_file.place.txt
rm: cannot remove â€˜dev_dataâ€™: Is a directory
ig_dir.sh: Removal of Source file failed
```

This is how I'm passing the parameter -- `sh -x ig_dir.sh.sh /alb/albt_shard/alb1/path1/path2/alb1/sub/alby`.. So when I pass this as argument to the script, it checks for the directory under **alby** and gives --- rm: cannot remove â€˜dev_dataâ€™: Is a directory

Comment: Note that making programmatic use of `ls` is itself a bad idea; see [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). With the `extglob` shell option enabled in bash, `rm !(test.txt)` is a means to remove all files except `test.txt` from the current directory; for something that works in non-bash shells, or bash where configuration isn't know, one can use `find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'test.txt' -prune -o -delete`

Comment: That said, I'm not clear on what this question is asking for as a whole. Why are you in one place trying to exclude test.txt and in another place trying to delete only things under dev_data? Are you trying to delete everything _except_ `test.txt` from every directory named `dev_data`? Please be explicit about what the goal is here.

Comment: (if you have `shopt -s extglob` set in bash, that might be `find ./**/dev_data -name test.txt -prune -o -delete`, but that's only if my guess at what you were trying to ask for is correct)

Comment: And how did a `tar` error message feature in the pipeline that doesn't mention tar?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I've also used a tar command in my script. I didn't mention the command here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"The script should remove only the files inside the directory - dev_data"*

```
find dev_data -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name test.txt -delete
```

- Specify your starting point as dev_data
- `-maxdepth 1` ensures it will not descend in dev_data sub-directories
- `! -name test.txt` ignores files named test.txt (the `!` is "not")
- you can add `-print` to get a list of deleted files